# Short story about humans finding out the afterlife is real, but you have to be buried on Earth

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I never read this short story, someone made a comment about it and never said the name of it. Apparently it's about humans millions of years after forming an interstellar civilization. They discovered that the afterlife is real, but in order to get there you have to be buried on Earth. Then there's a mass migration to Earth that starts a war. Some terrorists would rip dead bodies from their graves on Earth to rip their souls out of the afterlife. And that the farther from Earth you were buried the more in pain your soul would be.

Comment: Someone else (you?) seems to be looking for the same story https://www.reddit.com/r/scifi/comments/18vpie0/looking_for_a_short_story/ Except their question has info not contained in this one; *"humanity became a super advanced race and spread through the cosmos for millennia until it’s discovered that the afterlife exists, but you can only reach it if you are buried on Earth."* 1/2

Comment: *"Scientists create a way to see this “spirit world” to talk to spirits on other worlds, only to discover that the further the spirits are from Earth, the more anguish they’re in. A mass migration occurs with people wanting to go back to Earth, and I think a terrorist group pops up that launches corpses into space to rip spirits from the afterlife."* 2/2

Comment: Yes, that's the exact story i am looking for. Unfortunately i clicked the link you posted and no one has commented on his question. Also that person isn't me

Comment: Does any of that refresh your memory? Is there anything you want to [add to your question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/posts/283190/edit) now that you've read their question?

Comment: No. Like i said, i never read this story. I want to because it sounds like a interesting read but this is the only info i found from a comment in a obscure meme app. I tried contacting the commentor but no response yet